# Best configuration for Django staticfiles

Tags: python, django

In my Django project I have a **static** folder in the root of the project (near manage.py), so in settings.py, in order to find this static files I have:

> STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]

How do I have to configure `STATIC_ROOT`? Now I think about:

> STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

But when I run collectstatic it fails, static files are loaded but not in the admin site.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You want your static files in the admin app?

Answer (score 3):

`STATIC_ROOT` ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#static-root)) is the folder where every static files will be stored after a `manage.py collectstatic`

`STATICFILES_DIRS` ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#static-dirs)) is the list of folder where Django will search for additional static files, in addition to each static folder of each app installed.

So, if you use `[project_root]/static` directory as an additional folder you have to add it to `STATICFILES_DIRS` and use any other name for `STATIC_ROOT`

> STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'collected_static/')